# Convert SqlDataReader to a List of unknown types because of dynamic query

Tags: .net, list, sqldatareader

Friends,
I have a dynamic sql query that I would like to execute and return a list.
From most of my internet searches on goole, I found that the type of the list has to be known to convert the sqldatareader to a list.
How can I do that when I do not know what query will be executed.

```
Execute(String query)
{
  SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connection);//connection from elsewhere
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
  cmd.connection=con;
  con.Open();
  SqlDataReader result=cmd.ExecuteReader();
  //How to convert result to a list when i do not know the table structure 
}
```

Now I want to convert the result to a list. 
However I do not know the details of the table which the query works on.The query can vary, it can query any table. 
So under these conditions how can I convert the result to a list. Is it possible?

This leaves me with one simple question, if I do not know the table details, then what will be the entries of the list or it will be a list of what?

To answer that question, I ask myself another question, is it possible to have a list where each list entry will correspond to one row of the SqlDataReader result?

So I can use a List < DataRow > x =result.Select().ToList(), but I do not want to use this either.

I want each entry of the list to map to each row of the result and at the same time be composed of the atomic datatypes which make a row.

Eg **Select studentname,studentid from student;**
This will return me a SqlDataReader result and I want to construct a list whose type contains a string and an int and then populate the list with the rows of the result.

When the query changes to **select marks,subject,grade from marks where studentid=1432**, then I want to construct a list whose type contains int,string,char and then fill the list with the rows of the result.

Is there a way to do it?

PS The user knows how to pick the values if I return a list as detailed above, since he created the query and he knows how many columns to expect.

Comment: can't you use a SqlTableAdapter ? you'll get a collection of DataRow, whichever is the schema of the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the **caller** will know the type, make is a generic method, and create a `T` per row...

Or, since dapper-dot-net already does that:

```
var list = connection.Query<T>(command [, args]).ToList();
```

If the caller can't know the T either, you could use `ExpandoObject` to populate a `List<dynamic>`, casting the expando to `IDictionary<string,object>` to populate it with key/value pairs.

Or, since dapper-dot-net already does that:

```
var list = connection.Query(command [, args]).ToList();
```

Then the caller can use:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    Console.WriteList("{0}, {1}, {2}", item.marks, item.subject, item.grade);
}
```

Comment: Gravell, Super is the word! Thanks a lot, this is really helpful to achieve what I wanted. I also learnt something new today, Dapper dot net and ExpandoObject.